# Compare meta key separation

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I have a meta key called `$availability` that can have one of four options but also multiple values separated by pipe: `|`.

For example the value could be: `severaltimes_week|oncetwice_month|occasionally`.

I haven't found the right comparison operator for this issue, which one will work best?

```
if ( $_GET['ava1'] == "on" ) { $availability .= "severaltimes_week| "; }
if ( $_GET['ava2'] == "on" ) { $availability .= "oncetwice_week| "; }
if ( $_GET['ava3'] == "on" ) { $availability .= "oncetwice_month| "; }
if ( $_GET['ava4'] == "on" ) { $availability .= "occasionally"; }

$meta_args[] = array(
    'key' => 'availability',
    'value'   => $availability,
    'compare' => 'IN'
);
```

Comment: Have you tried 'LIKE'

Comment: yes. tried almost everything. I think I would need a solution with arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `LIKE` operator:

```
$meta_args[] = array(
    'key' => 'availability',
    'value'   => $availability,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```

In the codex you can see a list of [comparison operators](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: Also tried that but that also didn't work.

The problem is that the value can be just one of these four or more options separated by "|". 

Ava1 - Ava4 are four checkboxes. So if Ava1 and Ava2 are activated, I want to find all posts that contain "severaltimes_week" or "oncetwice_week", even if the value in the post is

e.g. "oncetwice_week| oncetwice_month| occasionally"

Comment: @user73437 try removing the `|` from the `$availability` value and just search for the string sans pipe.

Comment: Tried that too. doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

All of the comparison operators you list operate on whole strings except for `LIKE`, `NOT LIKE`, `REGEXP`, `NOT REGEXP`,`RLIKE`. However, using those operators is going to create very inefficient queries, and potentially unreliable ones. You are fighting with some of the basic design of MySQL with what you are doing.

Save your "availability" key as many times as you like-- that is, save distinct keys in the database with distinct values and not as the concatenated string. You can then search those key/values with a variety of operators as needed, and do so with relatively more efficient queries.

See Also: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/88715/21376

Comment: So what you mean is, I shouldn't have one key 'availability' that can contain up to four possible values. 

Instead I should have four keys each with a value of yes/no.
e.g.
'severaltimes_week' (yes/no)
'oncetwice_week' (yes/no)

do you really think that is needed?
Cause I would need to do a lot of changes.

Comment: I use "WP User Frontend Pro" plugin, where I got a lot of checkboxes that belong together in a checkbox field which is saved in a single meta value, as mentioned above. So it would be more confusing if all checkboxes would be single checkboxes. And doesn't it make the database bigger if I have a lot more metaboxes per post? So, I'm not sure if I really should change everything.

Comment: No. That is not what I said. Use one key with multiple values-- `__my_availability`, for example, with `severaltimes_week`, `oncetwice_week`, etc. The database size is not relevant. MySQL can handle a staggering number of rows. The big concern is query speed. What you are doing, and apparently what the plugin is doing, is inefficient int hat respect. It is common, but not a good idea. The number of key/values in the database doesn't have to reflect the number of metaboxes in the UI.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand, maybe due to my english and/or php knowledge. So, I can use one key with multiple values, as I already got. But key is called 'availability' and values are separated by "|" instead of ",". Is that a problem? So I don't really know what I can do in practice to make this work.

Comment: Save the **same** key name multiple times with different values. Look at the postmeta table you will numerous examples.

Comment: Ahh ok, I have forgotten that this is possible. The problem is that the custom fields are created and updated by WPUF plugin and that core functions of the plugins would need to be changed. So, there is no easier possibility. e.g. I could create if conditions which checkboxes are checked and create an array of possible values. Is that very bad behaviour?

Comment: That would leave you with the same or a more difficult problem with queries. This is why I use very few plugins that I haven't written, by the way.